# How to return a list with data from one array filtered by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm receiving two arrays from two different APIs. One of them have a full list of "Items", the other one is a list of some of these "Items". In real life words it could be like "Items that I already packed from all Items I need to pack". So, I need to return the list of packed Items and also the list of all remaining Items (full list minus already packed list).

```
const packedItems = [
  {
  "id": 03,
  "name": "Car",
    "color": {
      "inside": "grey",
      "outside": "blue"
    }
  },{
  "id": 07,
  "name": "Bike",
    "color": {
      "inside": null,
      "outside": "blue"
    }
  },
]

const allItems = [
  {
  "id": 01,
  "name": "Skateboard",
    "color": {
      "inside": "grey",
      "outside": "brown"
    }
  },{
  "id": 02,
  "name": "TV",
    "color": {
      "inside": "multiclolor",
      "outside": "black"
    }
  },{
  "id": 03,
  "name": "Car",
    "color": {
      "inside": "grey",
      "outside": "blue"
    }
  },{
  "id": 04,
  "name": "Pan",
    "color": {
      "inside": "grey",
      "outside": "black"
    }
  },{
  "id": 05,
  "name": "T-shirt",
    "color": {
      "inside": null,
      "outside": "white"
    }
  },{
  "id": 06,
  "name": "Helmet",
    "color": {
      "inside": "black",
      "outside": "black"
    }
  },{
  "id": 07,
  "name": "Bike",
    "color": {
      "inside": null,
      "outside": "blue"
    }
  },{
  "id": 08,
  "name": "Dryer",
    "color": {
      "inside": "white",
      "outside": "white"
    }
  },
]
```

Is expected to have two HTML UL: One with already packed Items, and another with the remaining Items that need to be packed.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you @musicfuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert your list of packed items to a simple list of ids. Then you can filter the `allItems` list rather simply.

```
const packedItemIds = packedItems.map(item => item.id);
const remainingItems = allItems.filter(item => {
  return !packedItemIds.some(id => id === item.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want to do is partition the array into two groups, based on whether the id is included in the list of packed items.  I would suggest writing a function that partitions an array based on an arbitrary predicate, and passing it a predicate that determines if the tested element has an id in a specific list.  It might look like this:

```js
const partition = (fn, xs) => xs .reduce (
  ([yes, no], x) => fn (x) ? [ [...yes, x], no ] : [ yes, [...no, x] ],
  [ [], [] ]
)
const hasId = (xs) => ({id}) => 
  xs .some ( ({id: pid}) => id === pid )

const partitionItems = (yes) => (maybe) => 
  partition (hasId (yes), maybe)

const allItems = [{"color": {"inside": "grey", "outside": "brown"}, "id": 1, "name": "Skateboard"}, {"color": {"inside": "multiclolor", "outside": "black"}, "id": 2, "name": "TV"}, {"color": {"inside": "grey", "outside": "blue"}, "id": 3, "name": "Car"}, {"color": {"inside": "grey", "outside": "black"}, "id": 4, "name": "Pan"}, {"color": {"inside": null, "outside": "white"}, "id": 5, "name": "T-shirt"}, {"color": {"inside": "black", "outside": "black"}, "id": 6, "name": "Helmet"}, {"color": {"inside": null, "outside": "blue"}, "id": 7, "name": "Bike"}, {"color": {"inside": "white", "outside": "white"}, "id": 8, "name": "Dryer"}]
const packedItems = [{"color": {"inside": "grey", "outside": "blue"}, "id": 3, "name": "Car"}, {"color": {"inside": null, "outside": "blue"}, "id": 7, "name": "Bike"}]

console .log (
  partitionItems (packedItems) (allItems)
)
```

Here `partition` is a clearly reusable function, and `hasId` might also be reusable.

Each function is simple, and each does a single job.